# Does php need a webserver like apache or nginx when being started by node js?

Tags: php, node.js

I just received this project that starts a php server using node js (didn't even know this could be done but I find it quiet strange since both are back end):

So my `index.js` is file is:

```
const phpServer = require('php-server');

(async () => {
    const server = await phpServer({ port: 3000 });
    console.log(`PHP server running at ${server.url}`)
})();
```

If I go to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` url, it works perfectly, but, how?, I mean, php DOES need a webserver, doesn't it?

Comment: it starts [php inbuilt server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), so no it doesn't need apache. [Source code](https://github.com/sindresorhus/php-server/blob/master/index.js)

Comment: When you see a `require` like that without a leading `./`, that means it's an npm package (usually). Google it, you'll find: https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-server

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Okay, so this server is just for development purposes, I get it, I don't know if you want to move your comment as an answer.

Comment: Neither PHP nor JavaScript or Node *need* a web server. You need a web server when you want, well, a program that serves HTTP requests. But there're many ways to implement a web server.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you can start your local built-in PHP development web server using the following command:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:PORT_NUMBER
```

So the package is just a wrapper around the previous command.
If you would like to try something nice, you can pass `0.0.0.0` as a hostname, this will make the server accessible from all devices on the network, after that run `ip addr` in your terminal (assuming you're on Linux), if you're on a laptop you should be looking for the IP address of a wireless interface, take that IP address and use it to access from any device on the same network.
Please note that this command is only meant for development and testing purposes, DO NOT use it for production.

Additional links that might be helpful:

- PHP built-in web server page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php